# How do I make the suffix visible in centos?

Tags: linux, centos

```
[root@vps303 menu]# ls
icons  jscookmenu  menu.php  _notes
[root@vps303 menu]# cat /etc/issue
CentOS release 5.4 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

As you see above,now the suffix is somehow invisible,how can I make them visible?

Comment: .​.​. W​h​at​​?

Comment: What do you mean by "suffix"?

Comment: Means extension.

Comment: If your intent was to show the version of the distribution, it's better to use `lsb_release -a` or `echo /etc/lsb-release`. You can show the kernel version using `uname -a`.

Answer (score 3):

I think by suffix you probably might mean the "extension", i.e. the .php in menu.php. The reason you don't see it is because it isn't there.  It is quite common in *nix for files to have no extension (This is also possible in Windows, but you don't see it as much).

If you mean hidden files, which in *nix are files that start with a period, (.settings), use `ls -al`.